# If $x + y + z + w=5$ then the minimum value of $x^2 \cot (9°) + y^2 \cot (27°) + z^2 \cot (63°) + w^2 \cot (81°)$ is?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, radicals, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I used the $A.M. \ge G.M.$ rule.

$$((xyzw)^2 . \cot(9^o)\tan(9^o)\cot(27^o)\tan(27^o))^{1/4} \le \space \frac {x^2 \cot (9°) + y^2 \cot (27°) + z^2 \cot (63°) + w^2 \cot (81°)}{4}$$

This reduces to :
$$4(xyzw)^{1/2} \le x^2 \cot (9°) + y^2 \cot (27°) + z^2 \cot (63°) + w^2 \cot (81°) ---- (1)$$

Now, I applied the same thing to the first equation:

$$ \frac {x+y+z+w}{4} \ge (xywz)^{1/4}$$
$$ \frac {5}{4} \ge (xywz)^{1/4}$$
$$ \frac {25}{16} \ge (xywz)^{1/2} ----(2)$$

Now I do not know what to do. From equation (2), I get the minimum value of $(xywz)^{1/2}$ as $- \infty$ (Am I right over here ?). In a nutshell, I am confused what to do next.

Comment: You can not use AM-GM here because your variables are reals.

Answer (score 3):

By C-S
$$\left(x^2 \cot 9° + y^2 \cot27° + z^2 \cot63° + w^2 \cot 81°\right)\left(\tan9^{\circ}+ \tan27^{\circ}+\tan63^{\circ}+\tan81^{\circ}\right)\geq(x+y+z+w)^2=25$$
The equality occurs for
$$\left(x\sqrt{ \cot 9°}, y\sqrt{ \cot27°}, z\sqrt{ \cot63°},w\sqrt{ \cot 81°}\right)||\left(\sqrt{\tan9^{\circ}}, \sqrt{\tan27^{\circ}},\sqrt{\tan63^{\circ}},\sqrt{\tan81^{\circ}}\right),$$
which gives the answer:
$$\frac{25}{\tan9^{\circ}+ \tan27^{\circ}+\tan63^{\circ}+\tan81^{\circ}}.$$
Done!

Comment: Can you explain the C-S Rule? If not, please provide me a link which I can refer to.

Comment: @Ishaan C-S it's the following. For all reals $a_i$ and $b_i$ we have $(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_n^2)\geq(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)^2$

Comment: @Ishaan It's called the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Nice, even better, you could've simplified to $\dfrac{5\sqrt5}4$.